# What is the use of HeaderedContentControl in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on WPF but the UI is localized for the  Gujarati language. In my window.xaml I have 2 rows and 2 columns.

I could not get use of the HeaderedContentControl tag.  The code is here:

```
<Border
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}"
            Padding="0"
            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
            Background="#f9f9f9">
            <HeaderedContentControl
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                Content="{Binding Path=CurrentWorkspace}"
                Style="{StaticResource MainWorkspaceStyle}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspaceTemplate}"/>
        </Border>
```

Please explain it and also explain role of content template.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `HeaderedContentControl` is a control that displays other controls, but also provides a header for that (like a `GroupBox` or window title).

The `HeaderedContentControl` is bound to a set of data-- in this case "CurrentWorkspace".

The `ContentTemplate` describes how that data should be displayed.  In this particular case, it is something called "WorkspaceTemplate", which will be defined as a Static Resource somewhere in the project-- either in a resource XAML file, or, perhaps in your window, under `<Window.Resources>` at the top of the XAML.

No matter where it is, if you search through your entire solution for `WorkspaceTemplate` you should eventually see where it is defined.

Comment: To add on to an already great answer: another example of a HeaderedContentControl is a tab page within a TabControl.  You can put whatever you want in the tab's header (often a string and a small graphic) in addition to displaying some content.

Comment: You can also use HeaderedControlControl directly in cases where you want a label positioned next to a control. This is one way to make the positioning of labels more consistent through an application.