# Creating a HeaderedContentControl with a border around

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've been asked to create in a WPF application a panel that has a text (as you can see in the picture, called Zona 0.

I've done this in the past in WinForm placing a TextBlock on the panel.
In WPF I've found this control HeaderedContentControl that creates the text but I've been unable to put a border around it, even if I've set the BorderTickness and BorderColor... what am I doing wrong?

I'm also using the Telerik suite, in case there's just a control that achieves this need.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GroupBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.groupbox?view=netframework-4.8) .

here is an example.

```
<GroupBox Header="YOUR_HEADER">

    <!-- Put your controls here -->

</GroupBox>
```

Maybe **not relevant** but here is a link what [HeaderedContentControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611491/what-is-the-use-of-headeredcontentcontrol-in-wpf) does. and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol?view=netframework-4.8) you can see how to use it.